# How do I get the "address consent token" after Amazon login?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using the OffAmazonPayments JS library to allow users to log into their Amazon account, access their address book, and eventually to pay with their Amazon account. The AddressBook widget will let me retrieve general address info, but without the address consent token, I cannot get the street address.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/off_amazon_payments/OffAmazonPayments_GetOrderReferenceDetails.html

This link indicates that I can retrieve the address consent token from the Button object after authentication, but it's not clear how that works; in the definition of the sign-in Button, there's an "onSignIn" callback which receives an orderReference object, but that object doesn't seem to contain any such token.

Comment: Please review the answer below to see if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the Amazon Payments documentation..specifically this page: https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/lpwa/201953150

As you can see in the following code snippet (taken from said page) you can retrieve the token from the "amazon.Login.authorize(...)" function.

**Note:** You first must include in the "scope" parameter "payments:shipping_address" as one of your scopes in order to get the "address consent token".  Below I'm including other scopes so you can see how to list more than one.

**The CAPS words/parameters would be replaced by your own desired parameters.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  var authRequest;
  var addressConsentToken;
  OffAmazonPayments.Button("AmazonPayButton", "YOUR_SELLER_ID", {
    type:  "ENTER_TYPE_PARAMETER",
    color: "ENTER_COLOR_PARAMETER",
    size:  "ENTER_SIZE_PARAMETER",
    language: "ENTER_LANGUAGE_PARAMETER",

    authorization: function() {
      loginOptions = {scope: "profile payments:widget payments:shipping_address", 
                      popup: "ENTER_POPUP_PARAMETER"};
      authRequest = amazon.Login.authorize (loginOptions,
        function(response) {
          addressConsentToken = response.access_token;
        });
    },
    onSignIn: function (orderReference) {
      var referenceId = orderReference.getAmazonOrderReferenceId();

      if (!referenceId) {
        errorHandler(new Error('referenceId missing'));
      } else {
        window.location = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URL" + '?referenceId=' + 
          orderReference.getAmazonOrderReferenceId() + 
          "&access_token=" + addressConsentToken;
      }
    },
    onError:errorHandler || function(error) {
      // your error handling code
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been running in circles for 2 hours trying to work out where the hell this param gets returned from...